# Sitecore Index for Image type

Tags: image, indexing, lucene, sitecore, sitecore7

I have created an index field to get/index an Image field from an item in Sitecore.
However, the index return the Alternate text of the image, but this is not very useful..

I have tried to add this line in Lucene index configuration

```
<field fieldName="restaurant_image" storageType="YES"  indexType="TOKENIZED"          vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
```

I need to get the Image path, or Image ID, or the image tag, but i have no idea how to do this..

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What version of Sitecore? That will define if it is a dynamic field or computed field.

Answer (score 2):

You could add a computed field.  [Here is John West's post about it.](http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2013/03/Sitecore-7-Computed-Index-Fields.aspx)   Below is a condensed example to get just the URL of the image.

Create a class that implements Sitecore.ContentSearch.ComputedFields.IComputedIndexField.

```
public class ImageIndexField : IComputedIndexField
{
    public string FieldName { get; set; }
    public string ReturnType { get; set; }

    public object ComputeFieldValue(IIndexable indexable)
    {
        Assert.ArgumentNotNull(indexable, "indexable");
        var indexableItem = indexable as SitecoreIndexableItem;

        if (indexableItem == null)
        {
            Log.Warn(string.Format("{0} : unsupported IIndexable type : {1}", this, indexable.GetType()), this);
            return null;
        }

        ImageField img = indexableItem.Item.Fields["MyImageField"];

        return img == null || img.MediaItem == null ? null : MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(img.MediaItem);
    }
}
```

Then, add a config include with something like this:

```
<sitecore>
    <contentSearch>
        <configuration type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
            <defaultIndexConfiguration type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneIndexConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
                <fields hint="raw:AddComputedIndexField">
                    <field fieldName="MyImageFieldUrl" storageType="YES" indexType="TOKENIZED">sc70.Search.ComputedFields.ImageUrlIndexField, sc70</field>
                </fields>
            </defaultIndexConfiguration>
        </configuration>
    </contentSearch>
</sitecore>
```

Note that the field name is hard coded above.  I'm not sure if it is possible to pass that in as a parameter from the config.  Sitecore seems to be creating separate classes for each of their computed fields and using inheritance to get reuse.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar using scSearchContrib in 6.6.

Created a Dynamic Field to get the image url

```
public class ImageUrlField : BaseDynamicField
    {
        public override string ResolveValue(Item item)
        {
                FileField fileField = item.Fields["Image"];

                var url = StringUtil.EnsurePrefix('/', MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(fileField.MediaItem));

                return url;            
        }
    }
```

Referenced in the config file as :-

```
<dynamicField type="[NAMESPACE].ImageUrlField, [DLL]" name="image url" storageType="YES" indexType="UN_TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f"  />
```

You should be able to do something similar in 7.0.

Comment: this might help me, but i am still confused.
in my class that handles the template , i have created the index like this:     [IndexField("restaurant_image")]
      public string RestaurantImage { get; set; }
and in the DefaultIndexConfig i added this line:    <field fieldName="restaurant_image" storageType="YES"  indexType="TOKENIZED"    vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
if i write restaurant.RestaurantImage, i get the Alternate text..