# Sitecore search with Lucene.Net: search in specific fields

Tags: sitecore, lucene.net

I'm using Lucene.Net and Sitecore.Search.Crawlers.DatabaseCrawler. At the moment, this search works for all fields, and I want to change it to search only  in a few fields.
I have custom crawler:

```cs
public class CustomCrawler : Sitecore.Search.Crawlers.DatabaseCrawler
{
    protected override void AddAllFields(Lucene.Net.Documents.Document document, Sitecore.Data.Items.Item item, bool versionSpecific)
    {  
        base.AddAllFields(document, item, versionSpecific);
        document.Add(new Field("title", item["TitleField"], Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.TOKENIZED));
        document.Add(new Field("image", imageUrl, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.TOKENIZED));      
    }

    protected override bool IsMatch(Item item)
    {
        if (!item.TemplateName.Contains("txttmpl")) return false;

        return base.IsMatch(item);
    }
}
```

I'm using title and image fields as a search result and displaying them on a web page:

```cs
var list = new List<SearchResult>();
foreach (var result in results)
{
    list.Add(new SearchResult()
    {
        Title = result.Document.GetField("title").StringValue(),
        Image = result.Document.GetField("image").StringValue()
    });
}

var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
httpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
httpContext.Response.Write(jss.Serialize(list));
httpContext.Response.Flush();
```

And in web.config file:

```xml
<index id="myindex" type="Sitecore.Search.Index, Sitecore.Kernel">
    <param desc="name">$(id)</param>
    <param desc="folder">Myfolder</param>
    <Analyzer ref="search/analyzer" />
    <locations hint="list:AddCrawler">
        <web type="Search.CustomCrawler, Search">
            <Database>web</Database>
            <Tags>web content</Tags>
            <Root>/sitecore/content/Site</Root>                             
            <Boost>2.0</Boost>
        </web>
    </locations>
</index>
```

The Solution above  search in all fields. How can I make it to search only in
certain fields? I've tryed document.RemoveField("SomeFieldName"), but it doesn't work. How to remove or add some fields? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can search specific fields by using the following search structure:

```
        SearchManager.GetIndex("my_index").Rebuild();

        using (IndexSearchContext indexSearchContext = SearchManager.GetIndex("my_index").CreateSearchContext())
        {
            // Field to be searched followed by search term
            Term term = new Term("location", "Ottawa");
            Query query = new TermQuery(term);

            SearchHits hits = indexSearchContext.Search(query, int.MaxValue);
            // Get Sitecore items from the results of the query
            List<Item> items = hits.FetchResults(0, int.MaxValue).Select(result => result.GetObject<Item>()).Where(item => item != null).ToList();
        }
```

The index can be set up to index all fields and this will continue to work:

```
     <index id="my_index" type="Sitecore.Search.Index, Sitecore.Kernel">
        <param desc="name">$(id)</param>
        <param desc="folder">dance_map_locations_index</param>
        <Analyzer ref="search/analyzer" />
        <locations hint="list:AddCrawler">
          <core type="Sitecore.Search.Crawlers.DatabaseCrawler,Sitecore.Kernel">
            <Database>web</Database>
            <Root>/sitecore/content/my first item/second item/parent item to be indexed</Root>
            <templates hint="list:IncludeTemplate">
              <template>{AD7E2747-695A-4AC8-A6AB-C7C6111AF9A7}</template>
            </templates>
          </core>
        </locations>
      </index>
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need a custom crawler for most of what you are trying to achieve.  You can add `<IndexAllFields>false</IndexAllFields>` inside your `<web>` node to keep it from adding all fields and then add a section like this:

```
<fields hint="raw:AddCustomField">
    <field luceneName="title" storageType="no" indexType="tokenized">TitleField</field>
    <field luceneName="image" storageType="yes" indexType="untokenized">imageUrl</field>
</fields>
```

However, since it looks like you're trying to add just the image src and not the full XML of an image field, you will probably want to use the Advanced Database Crawler and create a dynamicField. http://sitecorian.github.io/SitecoreSearchContrib/

Or, if you have the option of upgrading to Sitecore 7 you would create a computed field.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19588900/sitecore-index-for-image-type) for more detail on dynamic fields and computed fields